# Moving multiple files in directory that might have duplicate file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

can anyone help me with this?

I am trying to copy images from my USB to an archive on my computer, I have decided to make a BASH script to make this job easier. I want to copy files(ie IMG_0101.JPG) and if there is already a file with that name in the archive (Which there will be as I wipe my camera everytime I use it) the file should be named IMG_0101.JPG.JPG so that I don't lose the file.

```
#method, then
mv IMG_0101.JPG IMG_0101.JPG.JPG
else mv IMG_0101 path/to/destination
```

Comment: Rolled back your last edit, since you were substantially changing the question, and turning it into a duplicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238687/moving-multiple-files-in-directory-that-have-duplicate-file-names).

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in "$source"/*; do
    newfile="$dest"/"$file"
    while [ -e "$newfile" ]; do
        newfile=$newfile.JPG
    done
    cp "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

There is a race condition here (if another process could create a file by the same name between the first `done` and the `cp`) but that's fairly theoretical.

It would not be hard to come up with a less primitive renaming policy; perhaps replace `.JPG` at the end with an increasing numeric suffix plus `.JPG`?

Comment: I agree, I will add another couple of digits on the end, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the last modified timestamp of the file to tag each filename so if it is the same file it doesn't copy it over again.

Here's a bash specific script that you can use to move files from a "from" directory to a "to" directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in from/*
do
  filename="${f##*/}"`stat -c %Y $f`
  if [ ! -f to/$filename ]
  then
    mv $f to/$filename
  fi
done
```

Here's some sample output (using the above code in a script called "movefiles"):

```
# ls from
# ls to
# touch from/a
# touch from/b
# touch from/c
# touch from/d
# ls from
a  b  c  d
# ls to
# ./movefiles
# ls from
# ls to
a1385541573  b1385541574  c1385541576  d1385541577
# touch from/a
# touch from/b
# ./movefiles
# ls from
# ls to
a1385541573  a1385541599  b1385541574  b1385541601  c1385541576  d1385541577
```