# Moving multiple files in directory that have duplicate file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

can anyone help me with this?

I am trying to copy images from my USB to an archive on my computer, I have decided to make a BASH script to make this job easier. I want to copy files(ie IMG_0101.JPG) and if there is already a file with that name in the archive (Which there will be as I wipe my camera everytime I use it) the file should be named IMG_0101.JPG.JPG so that I don't lose the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ] 
then 
echo "Usage: $0 image_path archive_path"
exit 999
fi

if [ -d "$1" ] #Checks if archive directory exists
then
echo Image Source directory FOUND
else
echo ERROR: Image Source directory has NOT BEEN FOUND
fi

if [ -d "$2" ]
then
echo Photo Archive FOUND
else
echo Creating directory
mkdir "$2"
fi 

    if [ find $1 -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" ] #added this in to be more specific 1/4
    then #2/4
        for file in "$1"/*
        do

        dupefile= "$2"/"$file"
            while [ -e "$newfile" ];
            do
            newfile=$newfile.JPG
            done
        mv "$file" "$newfile"
        done
    else #3/4
    #do nothing
    fi #4/4 took all the /4 out, but it's saying theres no such file or directory, even though I've tested it and it says there is.
```

unexpected token fi is the error I'm getting but the if statement needs to be in there so the specific files i need, are getting moved.

Comment: Why not simply prefix each and everyfile with and index number ? Or you can even replace the whole name by this number since the name of the file seems of no importance to you.

Comment: You should make sure that you *never* overwrite any existing file with `mv`, not even due to a bug in your script. For this simply add option `-n` to `mv`.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up `newfile` and `dupefile`.  Stick to one or the other.

Comment: Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237133/moving-multiple-files-in-directory-that-might-have-duplicate-file-names

Comment: You should `exit` with a non-zero result code in the `ERROR` branch.  You cannot use result codes larger than 255, though.

Comment: If you want an else (or then) branch that does nothing then add a "noop" of `:`. See http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Some_Bash_Scripting_Notes.html

Comment: Or why not simply move the files into a subdirectory with a timestamp: `mkdir -p $archive_path/$(date +'%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an empty `else`.  Take out the `else` keyword if you don't have an `else` part.

Also, you should get rid of the superfluous `find`.  Just loop over the files you actually want instead.

```
for file in "$1"/IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG
do
    newfile= "$2"/"$file"
    while [ -e "$newfile" ];
    do
        newfile=$newfile.JPG
    done
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
    done
done
```

(This also addresses the `dupefile` vs `newfile` error.)

Comment: It is now saying that there is no such file or directory, even though I have put in a test and it says that they are there...

Comment: Fix your indentation and it will become a lot easier to see what belongs where.

Comment: There was an extra 'done' in there, it's now saying mv: cannot stat "$1(Obviously my source folder, which is correct as it is tested but there are no files exist.)"/IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG. I had >find $1 -name "IMG_[0-9]....JPG" -exec '{}' $2 \;< working which copied all the files but not the duplicates so I know there's a problem with the newer code

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the need to include some variables in quotation marks some not? I know dollar is used as substitutes but why quotation marks?

Comment: Basically, unless you *specifically* want the shell to split your variable on whitespace, use quotes.  Single quotes offer the most protection, double quotes allow variable expansion etc.  It's not like this isn't a [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: Assignments are the one exception to that rule.  `newfile=$newfile` could be written `newfile="$newfile"` but it isn't really necessary.